# Reading huge xml content issues in DOM parser in Blackberry?

Tags: dom, blackberry

**Hi All,** 
        I am developing one blackberry application which need to access XML content. I dont have any problem while i reading small content like single line string, but i am not able to read huge xml content. This is my XML content

```
HttpRequest httpRequest=new HttpRequest();
            InputStream inputStream=httpRequest.getInputStream(queryType);            
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            docBuilder.isValidating();
            doc = docBuilder.parse(inputStream);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            Element ele=doc.getDocumentElement();
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("items");
            System.out.println("items Length "+ nodeList.getLength()+"");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
            {
                Node root = nodeList.item(i);
                NodeList child=root.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("Length 1 "+ child.getLength()+"");
                for(int j=0;j<child.getLength();j++)
                {
                    Node subRoot=child.item(j);
                    NodeList subChild=subRoot.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("==>Result Value "+subRoot.getNodeName());
                    for(int k=0;k<subChild.getLength();k++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Node value=subChild.item(k);
                            if(value.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("overview"))
                            {                                                                               
                                overviewContent=value.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();                                                   
                            }                                                       
                            System.out.println("==>Result Value "+value.getNodeName()+" : "+value.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println(e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }                               
            }
```

This my HTML Content

> **WELCOME
>   …**
>
> ## 003366;">WARNING! - Your life may never be the same after downloading
>
> this cool 'know yourself'
>   tool… and it's
>   fun!
>
> ***Understand your relationships with your friends &
>   family!***
> Why
>   can't I relate to my
>   parents?
> Why do I argue
>   with my best friend?
>
> ## 003366;">***Find your Love-Match – in your fantasy or***
>
> for real!
>
> ## 003366;">Is my boyfriend/girlfriend right for me?
>
> style="color: #003366;">How does my
>   personality affect my
>   sex-life?
>
> ## 003366;">***Compare your personality with your favorite***
>
> celebrity or sports
>   star!
> What
>   about …
> Paris Hilton?
>   Tom Cruise? Hannah Montana? Justin
>   Bieber? Taylor Swift?Mick
>   Jagger? Ronaldo? or Justin Timberlake?
>   … to name a few! More
>   than 500 Musicians/Pop Stars, Sports
>   Stars, Celebrities, Film Stars etc.
>   online…!
>
> ## 003366;">***Make the right career choice!***
>
> />
>
> ## 003366;">What type of job will suit me best?
>
> style="color:
>
> ## 003366;">**It’s all about …** 
>
> style="color: #ffcc00;">p
>
> ## ffcc00;">ersonalit
>
> ## ffcc00;">y*,*
>
> ## ff0000;">personality*,*
>
> ## 3366ff;">per
>
> ## 3366ff;">sonality
>
> ## 003366;">!
>
> ## 003366;">Simply **answer 15 questions** and '
>
> style="color:
>
> ff0000;">click' to generate a report that gives you a
>
> **unique personality
>   profile** including your **individual**
>   combination of 
>   
>   **ffcc00;">YELLOW**,
>
> **ff0000;">RED** and
>
> **3366ff;">BLUE** personality
>
> traits. 
> **Press
>   the
>   '**
>   
>   **3366ff;">HELP****'**
>
> function if you want to read more
>   about the different personality types
>   and our system of color
>   coding.
>   
>   003366;">
>
> Complete your test, then you can check your
>
> style="color: #ff0000;">celebrity love
>   match and check your
>   personality with your friends, family
>   and your choice of over 500 stars we
>   have already listed
>   online.
>
>
>   
>   003366;">
>
> And what about your
>
> sexuality??? … and
>
> **career
>   choice**
>   
>   003366;">**???**
>
> />
>   
>   003366;">
>
> You can do 10 tests/reports and comparisons with
>
> family and friends 
>   
>   ff0000;">PLUS unlimited celebrity comparisons … DO IT
>
> NOW!
>
>
>   
>   003366;">**This system is so simple, 
>   
>   ff0000;">quick, easy and** 
>
> style="color:
>
> 3366ff;">accurate
>
> style="color: #003366;"> **- it
>   will amaze you!**
>
> 003366;">
>
> LET THE FUN BEGIN … Go test
>
> yourself!

I am not able find solution .

Thanks in advance.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse HTML while XML is expected. So, of course, parser fails because it expects a valid XML.

Comment: So how can parse this? is it possible? i successfully parsed in android Dom parser.

Comment: Probably Android's parser implementation is more advanced and was able to fix an invalid XML for you automatically. The content of the `<overview>` element should not contain any special character (e.g. '<', '>', '&', etc - check the XML format specs). Try to "preprocess" the HTML to escape those chars inside of the `<overview>` element.

Answer (score 0):

try to use xmlpullparse that will help surely because DOM and SAX return null value when single quote(') comes while parsing, that is not the case in xml pull parser.